# Is There any way to check if the entered key is having a corresponding value in a mapping or not?

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, mapping

Suppose In a banking system many people are enrolled (managed through mapping )
     `mapping (address => bool) enrolled;`

And only those can deposit who are enrolled in the bank.

Can I check if the msg.sender exists as a key in the above mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a bool in a mapping is `false`. If you also use `false` as a part of your tracking system, then no, you will not be able to tell whether a value has been set to `false` or has not been set at all.

For that, you may need a second mapping which tracks whether the value has been set before.

```
mapping (address => bool) enrolledSet;
```

Comment: Means for tracking a new mapping is needed we cant check or iterate through the mapping right ?

Comment: You cannot iterate through a mapping. You will need to create an array to do any sort of practical iterations since they have a measurable length and order. Otherwise, as I suggested in my answer, a mapping works to simply check whether the value has been set

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal way to cover random access, counting uniques and iterating over the list.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract InterableMapping {

    address[] public addressList;
    mapping(address => bool) public isAddress;

    function insertAddress(address customer) public {
        require(!isAddress[customer]);
        addressList.push(customer);
        isAddress[customer] = true;
    }

    function getAddressCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return addressList.length;
    }
}
```

You could add a soft delete by setting the `bool` to false.

```
function disableCustomer(address customer) public {
  require(isAddress[customer]);
  isAddress[customer] = false;
}
```

Have a look over here for different patterns: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with your example, you can just do the following:

```
require(enrolled[msg.sender]);
```